# Get parent name in Java / groovy

Tags: groovy, categories

I am reading a table with a category tree. Now I need to get an output with `name`, `id` and `parentname` of a category, but I can't figure out how to get the name of the parent.

```
def collect(path, item) {
    def line = item.id_ShopCOM + "|" + item.parent_guid + "|" + item.caption_ShopCOM
    outfile += line +"\n"
    println(line )
    x++ 
}
```

This way I can get the `parent_guid (Database ID)`, but how can I access the name of the parent within this loop?

Comment: To be more specific. In my Object, which I am reading, there is only the `parent_guid` stored which I can read as `item.parent_guid`. Now i need to load the parent object of the `item` to get its name somehow :/

Comment: `item.parent_name`. Or something else, hidden in the details you don't provide...

Comment: Question has not too much to Java / Groovy but  internal (unknown) structure of this object. What is source of data?

Comment: It is a SQL-Database. Within it there is the categorytree. In this tree there are the normal `items` which create the tree. The childs contain the `object_guid` of the `parent`. Sorry, what information more do you need? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a loop iteration handles just one item, the only way to access the parent's data is to do a lookup. You can do the lookup on-the-fly as you need it, or have the lookup data pre-processed.

Here's a Groovy-only simulation. You've got a list of items, basically what you'd get from the database. It's implemented as a `List<Map>`.

```
def tree = [
    [id: 1, parent: 3, name: 'root'],
    [id: 2, parent: 4, name: 'john'],
    [id: 3, parent: null, name: '/'],
    [id: 4, parent: 3, name: 'home']
]
```

The sample data above is the *NIX directories /, /root, /home, and /home/john.

The lookups will be by item ID, a good candidate for a `Map`. So the the `List<Map>` is converted to a `Map<Map>`.

```
def treeMap = tree.inject([:]) {map, item ->
    map[item.id] = item - [id: item.id]    
    map
}
```

The `Map` looks like this:

```
[
    1:[parent:3, name:'root'], 
    2:[parent:4, name:'john'], 
    3:[parent:null, name:'/'], 
    4:[parent:3, name:'home']
]
```

Now you can choose whether to do the parent lookups on-the-fly or from a pre-processed `Map`.

## On-the-fly

With an on-the-fly lookup you simply iterate through the `treeMap` and within each iteration lookup the parent's data using the same `treeMap`.

```
treeMap.each {id, item ->
    println "$id|$item.parent|$item.name|${treeMap[item.parent]?.name}"
}
```

## Pre-processed Map

With a pre-processed `Map` you basically replace the parent's ID with the  parent's data. Caveat, you may have to put the ID back in.

```
treeMap = treeMap.collectEntries {id, item -> 
    def parent = treeMap[item.parent]

    if(parent) parent.id = item.parent // Putting the ID back in.

    def newItem = item << [parent: parent]

    [(id): newItem] 
}

treeMap.each {id, item ->
    println "$id|${item.parent?.id}|$item.name|${item.parent?.name}"
}
```

## Output

Either way, the output is the same:

```
1|3|root|/
2|4|john|home
3|null|/|null
4|3|home|/
```